# Why is my JSON element not getting removed from the list?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I want to get the variable of that first element, as well as delete it.

But, the problem is that, even though there's no error, the element is still not being deleted.

Python Code:

```
import json

with open("listexamp.json") as list:
    b = json.load(list)

    print(b['addresses'][0])
    del b['addresses'][0]
```

listexamp.json File:

```
{"addresses":["addy1", "addy2", "addyn"]}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say delete it? Remove from the `b` variable or delete the text from the file?

Comment: I want to delete "addy1" from "addresses" as well as print/save it as a variable (before deleting)

Comment: Your code worked fine here, I've just needed to fix the "with" statement:
```
with open("listexamp.json") as list:
```

Comment: Also, side note, does that code really not give an error? The syntax of the `with` statement looks wrong to me

Comment: @dillon.harless, My bad on pasting the code here, but otherwise it does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are printing the values before deleting it :)

Correct code is

```
import json

with open("listexamp.json") as l:
    b = json.load(l)

    del b['addresses'][0]
    print(b['addresses'][0])
```

Outputs

```
python test.py
addy2
```

### With overriding the source file

```
import json

with open("listexamp.json") as l:
    b = json.load(l)

    del b['addresses'][0]
    print(b['addresses'][0])

with open("listexamp.json", 'w') as l:
    json.dump(b, l)
```

Comment: That code indeed deletes the first element **from the imported dictionary**, but my intention was to delete the element **from the JSON file itself.** How will i be able to do that?

Comment: override the file after deleting

Comment: @sanibani check my answer again

Comment: Yes, I got it what you mean with overriding. Thanks a lot.